# How bad is it to override a method from a third-party module?

Tags: python, numpy, overriding

How bad is it to redefine a class method from another, third-party module, in Python?

In fact, users can create NumPy matrices that contain [numbers with uncertainty](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncertainties/); ideally, I would like their code to run unmodified (compared to when the code manipulates float matrices); in particular, it would be great if the inverse of matrix `m` could still be obtained with `m.I`, despite the fact that `m.I` has to be calculated with my own code (the original `I` method does not work, in general).

How bad is it to redefine numpy.matrix.I?  For one thing, it does tamper with third-party code, which I don't like, as it may not be robust (what if other modules do the same?…).  Another problem is that the new numpy.matrix.I is a wrapper that involves a small overhead when the original numpy.matrix.I can actually be applied in order to obtain the inverse matrix.

Is subclassing NumPy matrices and only changing their `I` method better?  this would force users to update their code and create matrices of numbers with uncertainty with  `m = matrix_with_uncert(…)` (instead of keeping using `numpy.matrix(…)`, as for a matrix of floats), but maybe this is an inconvenience that should be accepted for the sake of robustness?  Matrix inversions could still be performed with `m.I`, which is good…  On the other hand, it would be nice if users could build all their matrices (of floats or of numbers with uncertainties) with `numpy.matrix()` directly, without having to bother checking for data types.

Any comment, or additional approach would be welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subclassing (which does involve overriding, as the term is generally used) is generally much preferable to "monkey-patching" (stuffing altered methods into existing classes or modules), even when the latter is available (built-in types, meaning ones implemented in C, can protect themselves against monkey-patching, and most of them do).

For example, if your functionality relies on monkey-patching, it will break and stop upgrades if at any time the class you're monkey patching gets upgraded to be implemented in C (for speed or specifically to defend against monkey patching).  Maintainers of third party packages hate monkey-patching because it means they get bogus bug reports from hapless users who (unbeknownst to them) are in fact using a buggy monkey-patch which breaks the third party package, where the latter (unless broken monkey-wise) is flawless.  You've already remarked on the possible performance hit.

Conceptually, a "matrix of numbers with uncertainty" is a different concept from a "matrix of numbers".  Subclassing expresses this cleanly, monkey-patching tries to hide it.  That's really the root of what's wrong with monkey-patching in general: a covert channel operating through global, hidden means, without clarity and transparency.  All the many practical problems descend in a sense from this root conceptual problem.

I **strongly** urge you to reject monkey-patching in favor of clean solutions such as subclassing.

Comment: Thank you for this lucid description of monkey patching and of its potential problems!  I must say NumPy encourages the definition of "arrays of something" by supporting them (`numpy.array([any_object])`).  So, I would say that "matrices of any-kind-of-object" is a concept very much supported by NumPy–element-wise addition is automatically supported etc.  That said, I fully subscribe to the rest of your response!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's perfectly acceptable to override methods that are ...

- Intentionally permit overrides
- In a way they document (satisfying [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) won't hurt)

If both conditions are met, then overriding should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean with "redefine". Obviously you can use your own version of it, no problem at all. Also you can redefine it by subclassing if it's a method.

You can also make a new method, and patch it into the class, a practice known as monkey_patching. Like so:

```
from amodule import aclass

def newfunction(self, param):
    do_something()

aclass.oldfunction = newfunction
```

This will make all instances of aclass use your new function instead of the old one, including instances in any "fourth-party" modules. This works and is highly useful, but it's regarded as very ugly and a last resort option. This is because there is nothing in the aclass code to suggest that you have overridden the method, so it's hard to debug. And even worse it gets when two modules monkeypatch the same thing. Then you *really* get confused.