# How to override stuff in a package at runtime?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, python-module, ietf-netconf

[EDIT: I'm running Python 2.7.3]

I'm a network engineer by trade, and I've been hacking on [ncclient](http://ncclient.grnet.gr/) (the version on the website is old, and [this](https://github.com/vbajpai/ncclient) was the version I've been working off of) to make it work with Brocade's implementation of NETCONF. There are some tweaks that I had to make in order to get it to work with our Brocade equipment, but I had to fork off the package and make tweaks to the source itself. This didn't feel "clean" to me so I decided I wanted to try to do it "the right way" and override a couple of things that exist in the package*; three things specifically:

1. A "static method" called build() which belongs to the HelloHandler class, which itself is a subclass of SessionListener
2. The "._id" attribute of the RPC class (the original implementation used uuid, and Brocade boxes didn't like this very much, so in my original tweaks I just changed this to a static value that never changed).
3. A small tweak to a util function that builds XML filter attributes

So far I have this code in a file `brcd_ncclient.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# hack on XML element creation and create a subclass to override HelloHandler's
# build() method to format the XML in a way that the brocades actually like

from ncclient.xml_ import *
from ncclient.transport.session import HelloHandler
from ncclient.operations.rpc import RPC, RaiseMode
from ncclient.operations import util

# register brocade namespace and create functions to create proper xml for
# hello/capabilities exchange

BROCADE_1_0 = "http://brocade.com/ns/netconf/config/netiron-config/"
register_namespace('brcd', BROCADE_1_0)

brocade_new_ele = lambda tag, ns, attrs={}, **extra: ET.Element(qualify(tag, ns), attrs, **extra)

brocade_sub_ele = lambda parent, tag, ns, attrs={}, **extra: ET.SubElement(parent, qualify(tag, ns), attrs, **extra)

# subclass RPC to override self._id to change uuid-generated message-id's;
# Brocades seem to not be able to handle the really long id's
class BrcdRPC(RPC):
    def __init__(self, session, async=False, timeout=30, raise_mode=RaiseMode.NONE):
        self._id = "1"
        return super(BrcdRPC, self).self._id

class BrcdHelloHandler(HelloHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        return super(BrcdHelloHandler, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def build(capabilities):
        hello = brocade_new_ele("hello", None, {'xmlns':"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"})
        caps = brocade_sub_ele(hello, "capabilities", None)
        def fun(uri): brocade_sub_ele(caps, "capability", None).text = uri
        map(fun, capabilities)
        return to_xml(hello)
        #return super(BrcdHelloHandler, self).build() ???

# since there's no classes I'm assuming I can just override the function itself
# in ncclient.operations.util?
def build_filter(spec, capcheck=None):
    type = None
    if isinstance(spec, tuple):
        type, criteria = spec
        # brocades want the netconf prefix on subtree filter attribute
        rep = new_ele("filter", {'nc:type':type})
        if type == "xpath":
            rep.attrib["select"] = criteria
        elif type == "subtree":
            rep.append(to_ele(criteria))
        else:
            raise OperationError("Invalid filter type")
    else:
        rep = validated_element(spec, ("filter", qualify("filter")),
                                    attrs=("type",))
        # TODO set type var here, check if select attr present in case of xpath..
    if type == "xpath" and capcheck is not None:
        capcheck(":xpath")
    return rep
```

And then in my file `netconftest.py` I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ncclient import manager
from brcd_ncclient import *

manager.logging.basicConfig(filename='ncclient.log', level=manager.logging.DEBUG)

# brocade server capabilities advertising as 1.1 compliant when they're really not
# this will stop ncclient from attempting 1.1 chunked netconf message transactions
manager.CAPABILITIES = ['urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:writeable-running:1.0', 'urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0']

# BROCADE_1_0 is the namespace defined for netiron configs in brcd_ncclient
# this maps to the 'brcd' prefix used in xml elements, ie subtree filter criteria
with manager.connect(host='hostname_or_ip', username='username', password='password') as m:
    # 'get' request with no filter - for brocades just shows 'show version' data
    c = m.get()
    print c
    # 'get-config' request with 'mpls-config' filter - if no filter is
    # supplied with 'get-config', brocade returns nothing
    netironcfg = brocade_new_ele('netiron-config', BROCADE_1_0)
    mplsconfig = brocade_sub_ele(netironcfg, 'mpls-config', BROCADE_1_0)
    filterstr = to_xml(netironcfg)
    c2 = m.get_config(source='running', filter=('subtree', filterstr))
    print c2
    # so far it only looks like the supported filters for 'get-config'
    # operations are: 'interface-config', 'vlan-config' and 'mpls-config'
```

Whenever I run my `netconftest.py` file, I get timeout errors because in the log file `ncclient.log` I can see that my subclass definitions (namely the one that changes the XML for hello exchange - the staticmethod `build`) are being ignored and the Brocade box doesn't know how to interpret the XML that the original ncclient `HelloHandler.build()` method is generating**. I can also see in the generated logfile that the other things I'm trying to override are also being ignored, like the message-id (static value of 1) as well as the XML filters.

So, I'm kind of at a loss here. I did find [this blog post/module](http://blog.rabidgeek.com/?p=126) from my research, and it would appear to do exactly what I want, but I'd really like to be able to understand what I'm doing wrong via doing it by hand, rather than using a module that someone has already written as an excuse to not have to figure this out on my own.

*Can someone explain to me if this is "monkey patching" and is actually bad? I've seen in my research that monkey patching is not desirable, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201106/1921885) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496221/1921885) are confusing me quite a bit. To me, my desire to override these bits would prevent me from having to maintain an entire fork of my own ncclient.

**To give a little more context, this XML, which `ncclient.transport.session.HelloHandler.build()` generates by default, the Brocade box doesn't seem to like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <nc:hello xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
        <nc:capabilities>
            <nc:capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0</nc:capability>   
            <nc:capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:writeable-running:1.0</nc:capability>   
        </nc:capabilities>
    </nc:hello>
```

The purpose of my overridden `build()` method is to turn the above XML into this (which the Brocade does like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hello xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
        <capabilities>
            <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0</capability>
            <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:writeable-running:1.0</capability>
        </capabilities>
    </hello>
```

Comment: Your code will generate NameErrors because names like `BROCADE_1_0` are not defined in nfconftest.py.  You're not posting the code you're running.  That said, it looks like the `OPERATIONS` dict in `manager` is meant to let you do this sort of thing.  Did you look at that?

Comment: No name errors are being generated during runs of `netconftest.py` about `BROCADE_1_0` because I've imported `brcd_ncclient` which defines them.... the `OPERATIONS` dict is just a fancy map to `ncclient.operations.rpc.Method` and this isn't what I really want to change. I'm not sure what you mean about posting the code I'm running. I've posted the code I'm running.

Comment: Importing `brcd_ncclient` will not make the names available in netconftest.py.  You would have to use `from brcd_ncclient import *`, or access the names via `brcd_ncclient.BROCADE_1_0`, etc.

Comment: That's interesting - so you're right, if I just do an `import brcd_ncclient` and try `print BROCADE_1_0` I do get a NameError, but `netconftest` runs don't generate these. Nonetheless I fixed the import statement above and in my code (and was secretly hoping this would also solve my problem, but it didn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the "meta info" should not have been so hastily removed, because again, it's difficult to find answers to what I'm after when I don't fully understand what I want to ask. What I really wanted to do was override stuff in a package ***at runtime***.

Here's what I've changed `brcd_ncclient.py` to (comments removed for brevity):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ncclient import manager
from ncclient.xml_ import *

brcd_new_ele = lambda tag, ns, attrs={}, **extra: ET.Element(qualify(tag, ns), attrs, **extra)
brcd_sub_ele = lambda parent, tag, ns, attrs={}, **extra: ET.SubElement(parent, qualify(tag, ns), attrs, **extra)

BROCADE_1_0 = "http://brocade.com/ns/netconf/config/netiron-config/"
register_namespace('brcd', BROCADE_1_0)

@staticmethod
def brcd_build(capabilities):
    hello = brcd_new_ele("hello", None, {'xmlns':"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"})
    caps = brcd_sub_ele(hello, "capabilities", None)
    def fun(uri): brcd_sub_ele(caps, "capability", None).text = uri
    map(fun, capabilities)
    return to_xml(hello)

def brcd_build_filter(spec, capcheck=None):
    type = None
    if isinstance(spec, tuple):
        type, criteria = spec
        # brocades want the netconf prefix on subtree filter attribute
        rep = new_ele("filter", {'nc:type':type})
        if type == "xpath":
            rep.attrib["select"] = criteria
        elif type == "subtree":
            rep.append(to_ele(criteria))
        else:
            raise OperationError("Invalid filter type")
    else:
        rep = validated_element(spec, ("filter", qualify("filter")),
                                attrs=("type",))
    if type == "xpath" and capcheck is not None:
        capcheck(":xpath")
    return rep

manager.transport.session.HelloHandler.build = brcd_build
manager.operations.util.build_filter = brcd_build_filter
```

And then in `netconftest.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from brcd_ncclient import *

manager.logging.basicConfig(filename='ncclient.log', level=manager.logging.DEBUG)

manager.CAPABILITIES = ['urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:writeable-running:1.0', 'urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0']

with manager.connect(host='host', username='user', password='password') as m:
    netironcfg = brcd_new_ele('netiron-config', BROCADE_1_0)
    mplsconfig = brcd_sub_ele(netironcfg, 'mpls-config', BROCADE_1_0)
    filterstr = to_xml(netironcfg)
    c2 = m.get_config(source='running', filter=('subtree', filterstr))
    print c2
```

This gets me almost to where I want to be. I still have to edit the original source code to change the message-id's from being generated with `uuid1().urn` because I haven't figured out or don't understand how to change an object's attributes before `__init__` happens at runtime (chicken/egg problem?); here's the offending code in `ncclient/operations/rpc.py`:

```
class RPC(object):
    DEPENDS = []
    REPLY_CLS = RPCReply
    def __init__(self, session, async=False, timeout=30, raise_mode=RaiseMode.NONE):
        self._session = session
        try:
            for cap in self.DEPENDS:
                self._assert(cap)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self._async = async
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._raise_mode = raise_mode
        self._id = uuid1().urn # Keeps things simple instead of having a class attr with running ID that has to be locked
```

Credit goes to [this recipe on ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/92823-howto-change-the-implementation-of-a-method-at-run/) for finally cluing me in on what I really wanted to do. The code I had originally posted I don't think was technically incorrect - if what I wanted to do was fork off my own ncclient and make changes to it and/or maintain it, which wasn't what I wanted to do at all, at least not right now.

I'll edit my question title to better reflect what I had originally wanted - if other folks have better or cleaner ideas, I'm totally open.